# I need to run an if statement on an sql query, with variable provided or empty

Tags: python, flask, sqlite

I understand basically that my SQL statement will not run if it has no variable listed, because what I want do do is check to see if a name exists before writing to it (I can probably do this within SQL).  I understand the issue, just not how to correct it...  Figured I'd ask now before it's 9:30pm and I'm still digging around the issue.  Thanks

app.py

```
import sqlite3
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from tabledef import *
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///tutorial.db', echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

USERNAME = "Jas"
PASSWORD = "Booger"
EMAIL = "jason@jason.com"
AMOUNT = "500"
reg = User(USERNAME, PASSWORD, EMAIL, AMOUNT)

conn = sqlite3.connect("tutorial.db")
c = conn.cursor()
try:
    c.execute('SELECT username from users WHERE username = "%s"' % USERNAME)
    result = str(c.fetchall()).split("'")[1]
    print result
except ValueError as e:
    print e
```

Error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sysadmin/PycharmProjects/bet1/app3.py", line 18, in <module>
    result = str(c.fetchall()).split("'")[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you're asking, but I suggest you read the following section from the [Python manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#):

```
# Never do this -- insecure!
symbol = 'RHAT'
c.execute("SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol = '%s'" % symbol)

# Do this instead
t = ('RHAT',)
c.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol=?', t)
print c.fetchone()
```

In addition to preventing SQL injection attacks, it also uses fetchone() instead of... converting your response to a string and parsing it again.

Comment: That makes sense and I'll be sure to incorporate that to remove the escape and other unwanted characters.  What I'm asking is if you had either of those variables above the c.execute empty, I'm going to get that error because the query returned nothing.  I think I can figure this one out, I just found SELECT EXISTS statement on line which would save me the time, but thanks for the SQL-inj info.

Comment: Hmm, it appears if my variables are going to be coming from a form, the above method will still allow for a user to inject code from the POST.  So it appears I'll still have to do some escaping, correct?  Or is there a better way to prevent injected code coming from forms?

Comment: This method should automatically escape everything correctly.